# small folders icon in my Windows 7 are corrupted

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

Firstly, see the following picture:

[image]

As you saw, all those are folders, and this problem happens when changing the icons view to (small icons, list and details), but when change the icons view to the large icons like (tiles, medium icons and large icons) the problem does not occur.

That problem happened after changing the default folders icon from the registry as follows:

[image]

But after that, I have retrieved everything as it was, but unfortunately, this problem occurred.

**What I have tried:**

- I have deleted the IconCache.db file.

Now, how can I retrieve all folder icons to the default icon?

Comment: @Ramhound: But that problem did not exist before and it happened after changing in the Windows registry.

Comment: That keys did not exist before, but I'm who added that keys to the registry.
So, I have deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound: A tutorial like this [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZ_JoHUpLpY)